# How to remove blank image container?

Tags: html

How can I remove a blank image container if the image's source is unavailable please? I would only like the image to appear if its source is available. Otherwise, I don't want anything to appear, including the blank container.

HTML image syntax:

```
<img src="url" alt="some_text">
```

Comment: The only way I can see this working is with JavaScript?

Comment: no problem, open to all solutions

Comment: The ideal thing to do would be not to show the image tag at all if it doesn't exist. This would require server side processing though

Comment: <img src="url" alt="img" onerror="this.style.display='none';" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to do this using JavaScript and the `error` event on the img tag.

For example:

```
<img src="url" alt="some_text" id="myimage">

<script>
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('myimage');
    imgElement.addEventListener('error', function()
    {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }, true);
</script>
```

*(Oops, sorry @JosephSilber, modified my example to be a bit different ;-))*

Your best bet would be using server-side processing if you know that your image isn't going to be available. If you're intentionally leaving the `src` blank, for example, you can do something like this in PHP:

```
<?php
$src = ''; // or something else

if (!empty($src)) { ?>
    <img src="<?=$src?>" alt="some_text" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ( ! empty($src) )`?

Comment: The JavaScript bit will not work reliably. The error handler needs to be set before the image is loading.

Comment: @JosephSilber Indeed, that's what comes from late night overflowing ;-) @pekka I just ran a quick test, and this surprisingly worked (IE10). I know when creating the DOM `Image` from JS it needs to be set before `src`, but without setting it inline with the `img` tag there's little more that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your images, and bind `onerror`:

```
imgNode.onerror = function () {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
```

Comment: IIRC `onerror` is incredibly unreliable for images, though. Let me see whether I can find a source

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Yeah. I think Safari doesn't implement it.

Comment: Yeah. Doing a quick Google, it seems less unreliable than I remembered though. Just make sure you bind the event *before* setting the `src`

Comment: @Pekka웃 - The problem though is that the image `src` is set in the original markup. I've searched around a bit, but can't find a solution for that. Any help?

Comment: the only 100% reliable way that I can think of would be to set the `onerror` attribute directly in the HTML. Yuck!